# How to use search pipe with pagination in ngFor using angular 4

Tags: angular, search, pagination, pipe

I have the below code for search pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'pkhospitalparam'
})
export class PkhospitalparamPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], searchString: string ) {

    if (!searchString) {
      console.log('no search');
      return value;
    }

    return value.filter(it => {
        const hospitalName = it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase());

        return (hospitalName);
    });
 }

}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchHospitalParam"  />

             <div *ngFor="let result of resultArray | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p } | pkhospitalparam:searchHospitalParam"></div>
```

I have passed the pipe param in ngFor and it works fine. The problem is since I have pagination ( around 50 pages) implemented, the search doesnt happen for 50 pages altogether. Search filters only on the page where I am . Is there anyway to do a global search for all pages?

Comment: can we see the paginate pipe as well?

Comment: When doing the pagination and filtering of data you should first filter the data and then paginate it, not the other way around. Because after you paginate it you don't have whole data in hands to filter it.

Comment: great !! it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is quite old but might be helpful to others,

worked for me by making use of the w-ng5 component

1) install via npm

```
npm install w-ng5 --save
```

2) after installing import module in app.module.ts

```
import { PipesModule } from 'w-ng5';
```

3) add in imports section of app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    PipesModule,
 ]
```

4) now you can filter by using

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchHospitalParam"/>
   <div *ngFor="let result of resultArray | filter:searchHospitalParam" | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p } | ></div>
```

*NB You should be filtering first before paginating

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a little error, because when I'm using `w-ng5` it doesnt filter in a correct way, only shows a blank list, can you help me with this trouble?

Comment: can u post a new question describing the trouble you are encountering

Comment: Hey bro, this is the [question of my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125989/trying-to-filter-data-in-ngfor-directive-with-w-ng5), regards!