# Trying to filter data in *ngFor directive

Tags: angular

I'm trying to filter my array data on a table from Angular with the package `w-ng5`, but it's searching and it doesn't find nothing (blank list). This is the steps that I've followed:

**package npm**

Here you can find the documentation of [w-ng5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/w-ng5) for Angular.

**Steps**

Install the package with `npm`

```
npm install w-ng5 --save
```

Import in the module of my aplication

```
//Pipes of the aplication
import { TruncatePipe } from './pipes/truncate.pipe';
import { PipesModule } from 'w-ng5';
```

Declare section of app.module

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    ColorPickerModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
    CurrencyMaskModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    NgxTypeaheadModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
```

And the implementation:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterInvoice" name="filterInvoice">
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
  <caption>Tabla de Facturas</caption>
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th class="text-center">Invoice</th>
      <th class="text-center">Note</th>
      <th class="text-center">State</th>
      <th class="text-center">Customer</th>
      <th class="text-center">Date</th>
      <th class="text-center">Days</th>
      <th class="text-center">Expiration</th>
      <th class="text-center">Payment Type</th>
      <th class="text-center">Option</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices | filter : filterInvoice | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }, index as i">
       <td class="text-center">
          {{i+1}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.number_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.note_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.state_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.customer_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.date_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.days_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.expiration_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          {{invoice.payment_invoice}}
       </td>
       <td class="text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
             Detail
          </button>
       </td>
     </tr>         
   </tbody>        
</table>
```

**Data table JSON**

```
invoices:any[] =[
    {
      number_invoice: '996',
      note_invoice: '0001',
      state_invoice: 'pending',
      customer_invoice: 'Johan Corrales',
      date_invoice: '2018-10-30',
      days_invoice: '30',
      expiration_invoice: '2018-11-30',
      payment_invoice: 'Credit'
    },
    {
      number_invoice: '997',
      note_invoice: 'N/A',
      state_invoice: 'Pay out',
      customer_invoice: 'Richard Castle',
      date_invoice: '2018-10-30',
      days_invoice: '0',
      expiration_invoice: 'N/A',
      payment_invoice: 'Credit'
    },
    {
      number_invoice: '998',
      note_invoice: 'N/A',
      state_invoice: 'pending',
      customer_invoice: 'Kyara Wolff',
      date_invoice: '2018-10-30',
      days_invoice: '30',
      expiration_invoice: '2018-11-30',
      payment_invoice: 'Credit'
    },
    {
      number_invoice: '999',
      note_invoice: 'N/A',
      state_invoice: 'pending',
      customer_invoice: 'Donaldo Trumpete',
      date_invoice: '2018-10-30',
      days_invoice: '30',
      expiration_invoice: '2018-11-30',
      payment_invoice: 'Credit'
    },
    {
      number_invoice: '1000',
      note_invoice: '0001',
      state_invoice: 'pending',
      customer_invoice: 'Mark Wahlber',
      date_invoice: '2018-10-30',
      days_invoice: '30',
      expiration_invoice: '2018-11-30',
      payment_invoice: 'Cash'
    },
    {
      number_invoice: '1001',
      note_invoice: 'N/A',
      state_invoice: 'Pay out',
      customer_invoice: 'Ryan Reynolds',
      date_invoice: '2018-10-30',
      days_invoice: '0',
      expiration_invoice: 'N/A',
      payment_invoice: 'Cash'
    },
  ]
```

**Service Invoice**

```
  public getInvoice()
  {
    return new Promise(
      resolve=>{
        this.http.get('authentication/consultInvoice')
        .subscribe(
        data => resolve(data)
        )
      }
    )
  };
```

**Constructor Component**

```
constructor(private _serviceInvoice:InvoiceService)
  {    
    _serviceInvoice.getInvoice()
    .then(data=>{
      this.invoices = data;
      this.onFilterChange();
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
```

And this is the error that I'm getting from Angular> `ERROR TypeError: "item is null; can't access its "toString" property"`

**Notes**
I know about this(docs from Angular):

> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user
>   experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when
>   Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second

Comment: Looks like `filterInvoice` is a string, which won't work for filtering objects according to those docs. For what it's worth, the officla angular docs [suggest not to use pipes for filtering anyway](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: Yes, I know that. It's a great sacrifice to get a real filter, and I've waste my time finding a real solution to this. And, this was a better solution that I could find. If you have another way to do this, you can tell me.. I'm here listening new options, thanks!

Comment: Well I'm not sure what your data looks like, nor what your desired behaviour is, but I'd suggest making use of the `filter` function that exists on arrays

Comment: You can make your custom filter pipe, to filter data

Comment: @suryan can you show me an example of that?

Comment: @user184994 I've updated my question with a little image to show you how its my data...

Comment: It would be far easier to create an example if you can provide JSON rather than an image

Comment: @user184994 I've put an little example of my JSON service!

Comment: Here is the implementation of your example with the filter component, working in several scenarios. wngx-filter (formerly w-ng5) now works with simple or complex nested filters.

[1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wngx-filter

Comment: Thank you my friend, it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a filter function that is called whenever your filter string changes.

The code will look something like this:

```
  isMatch(item) {
    if (item instanceof Object) {
      return Object.keys(item).some((k) => this.isMatch(item[k]));
    } else {
      return item.toString().indexOf(this.filterString) > -1
    }
  }
```

This will iterate through the object recursively, and look for any matches. While it's not necessary (seeing as your object structure is flat), it could be useful if your structure ever changes. Bear in mind it's case sensitive as it stands

You then need to create a function that calls it, like so:

```
onFilterChange() {
  this.filtered = this.invoices.filter((invoice) => this.isMatch(invoice));
}
```

And amend your input so that it refilters any time that the search string is changed

```
<input [(ngModel)]="filterString" (ngModelChange)="onFilterChange()" />
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zetnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: So, is this a better way to avoid losing the user experience?

Comment: Unlike a pipe, this will only perform the filtering any time the actual filter value changes, so it should be more performant

Comment: Ok bro, I have another problem, I'm getting the data from a service, and in this case `this.invoices.filter((invoice) => this.isMatch(invoice));` the result it's **ERROR TypeError: "item is null; can't access its "toString" property"**, do you know why? *Note:* if I use the array on my component just like in your expample in StackBlits it works...

Comment: Hard to say, but it sounds like `item` is null. Is `this.invoices` an array? Try doing a `console.log` at the start of the `isMatch` function and see what's logged

Comment: Hi, `Invoices:  Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]` its the array data on the component and `Data:  
Array(81) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]` its the data from the service, and it's printing this 8 or 9 times when I'm wrinthing on the input

Comment: I'm not sure without being able to see the data. Is the data confidential, or can you add the JSON to a pastebin somewhere? If not, I'd suggest just adding a null check into the `isMatch` function so it doesn't call `toString()` if `item` is null

Comment: Hey bro, that works! thanks for your help. I've just checked if it's null or not...

Answer (score 1):

you can filter array data on each column of a table still using  w-ng5 module

simply change

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices | filter : filterInvoice | 
    paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }, index as i">
```

to

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices | filter:[
    {field:'number_invoice', value: searchValue}, 
    {field:'note_invoice', value: searchValue}, 
    {field:'state_invoice', value: searchValue}, 
    {field:'customer_invoice', value: searchValue},
    {field:'date_invoice', value: searchValue},
    {field:'days_invoice', value: searchValue},
    {field:'expiration_invoice', value: searchValue}, 
    {field:'payment_invoice', value: searchValue}] | 
    paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }, 
 index as i">
```

This will repeatedly check  through the object, and look for similarities

Answer (score 0):

Good night!

So, please tell w-ng5 that your filter is not applied to a simple string structure but rather to a complex object. To do this, in the filter syntax in * ngFor, use the following format:

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices | filter : [
                                            {field:'number_invoice' , value:filterInvoice}, 
                                            {field:'note_invoice' , value:filterInvoice},
                                            {field:'customer_invoice' , value:filterInvoice},
                                            {field:'payment_invoice' , value:filterInvoice}
                                            ] 
         paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }, index as i">
```

I implemented your stackblitz example, however, I removed the paging pipes: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vlzd3f](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wngx-filter)

***Note that for complex objects, you need to tell the filter which attributes you want to apply the filter to***. In the example I implemented, I applied the filter over the four fields: number_invoice, note_invoice, customer_invoice e payment_invoice

**However, note that the component has been upgraded to a version already with angle 7 and with a new feature, it has now ignored accents in the filtered values. The new component name also changed to wngx-filter** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wngx-filter).

Hope this helps