# Pipe that supports lowercase and includes searched value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this search pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter2'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(singleItem => {
      return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && value.includes(singleItem[field].toLowerCase()) && value.indexOf(singleItem[field].toLowerCase()) >= 0);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work properly. For example if I have this value in my table `JOHN`, if I search by `john` it won't find it (case sensitive).

Also, if I search after 'JO' it won't find the value. I tried something like `value.includes(singleItem[field].toLowerCase())` but it's still not finding my value.

How can I modify my code in order to work? Thank you for your time!

Comment: [Filter pipes are discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

Comment: I don't know how to do this in another way. Can you give me an advice? @trichetriche

Comment: [`The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filtered[Collection] or sorted[Collection] property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic`](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125989/trying-to-filter-data-in-ngfor-directive/53126439#53126439 for an example

Comment: Shouldn't it be     items.includes(singleItem[field].toLowerCase()) ??

Comment: @user184994  will that work if I have multiple filters?

Comment: You'll need to modify it slightly for that to work. You can change the 2nd return to something like `return this.filters.some((filter) => new RegExp(filter, "i").test(item.toString()))`. You'll want to move where you instantiate `new RegExp` so it's not called more times than necessary though.